# AADSTS90093: This operation can only be performed by an administrator

Tags: azure, skype, skype-for-business

I am running [Skype Web SDK samples](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-samples/tree/master/SkypeWebSDKOnlineSample) locally using IIS manager. 
The user with profile Global administrator able to login successfully.

The normal users not able to login to application and getting bellow error message.

> Additional technical information:
>
> Correlation ID: 3c0fc0a3-eecc-4c32-8596-de1118be0f82
>
> Timestamp: 2017-01-30 13:33:18Z
>
> AADSTS90093: This operation can only be performed by an administrator.
>   Sign out and sign in as an administrator or contact one of your
>   organization's administrators.

Kindly help to resolve login issue for normal users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using multiple tenants?
In that case, you first need to delegate authority to the application by the tenant administrator.
Please try the authorize URL of the following site (rewrite the parameters)

[Microsoft Graph app authentication using Azure AD](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization)

### Update

In order to use delegation of authority, you must understand the concept of "admin consent". The actual method is explained in detail on this site.

[Admin Consent for Permissions in Azure Active Directory](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2017/01/24/Admin-Consent-for-Permissions-in-Azure-Active-Directory.aspx)

Comment: Yes I am using multiple tenants. Could you elaborate this part "delegate authority to the application" how to do this?

Comment: @satishakumar-awati It is a mechanism to delegate the administrator authority to the application. I added a link explaining that

Comment: Link helped thanks.

Permission set to include the “Read directory data” permission - this worked for me.